# Designing a query class for database

Tags: sql, database, jdbc

I am writing an application that interacts with databases. I want to use `PreparedStatement` to execute the query, but the number of queries that I have to do is high and may increase in future.
I only know to write a function for a particular query to execute it and cannot think of a better way to do it.

For example queries can be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE_NAME 
WHERE  TABLE_NAME.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = ?
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE_NAME 
WHERE  TABLE_NAME.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = ?
       AND TABLE_NAME.ATTRIBUTE_NAME1 = ?
```

and I will have to write an independent function to execute both([an example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) of how to do it for one query), but I know that this isn't a modular way to do this.

Is there better way to do it?

Comment: Why don't get a look to Spring JDBC support and simply use DAO/Service to perform query? DAO/Service are just a pattern, can be used outside spring context

Comment: @bellabax I did not knew about this. I have worked only on `jdbc` in past. Please feel free to elaborate if there is some other way to do it(although I will check it out).

Answer (score 0):

IMO a really good solution can be use [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) library.
Just

- create your database schema
- connect to database
- use fluent API to create your query based on your generated database
  schema metamodel

(You can also use as simple SQL-executor like described [here](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-sql-executor/))
Done. This is your library.

After, to separate from your program context, create an interface like

```
interface MyOperations {
  public int getUserById(int userID);
}

class MyOperationsImpl implements MyOperations {

  public MyOperationsImpl(Connection connection) {...}

  int getUserById(int userID) {
    DSLContext create = DSL.using(this.connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    create.select().from(USERS).where(USERS.ID.equal(userID));
  }
}
```

This can answer your question or help in some way?